# Algebra Math Puzzle sum of squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can I get some help with this question:

Two numbers are such that sum of their cubes is 14 and the sum of their squares is 6. Find the sum of the two numbers.

All I have got so far is:
$$
x^3 + y^3 = 14 \quad\quad x^2 + y^2 = 6
$$

Please help.

Comment: Try multiplying out $(x+y)^3$ and see if you can make some progress...

Comment: Sorry can you explain

Comment: Did you actually multiply it out?  What did you get?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche:  I think it's the number of solutions.

Comment: @user3521029, Eric Towers is saying that you should try expanding the product $(x+y)(x+y)(x+y)$.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo error I made. It is asking for the sum of the two numbers. Edited the question.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I tried that but I got imaginary numbers for my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=x+y$ and $b=xy$. Then:
$$
(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3 \Rightarrow a^3=14+3ab
$$
$$
(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy \Rightarrow a^2=6+2b
$$
Hence the second one give us: $b=\frac{a^2-6}{2}$ and substituting in the first one we find that:

$$
a^3=14+\frac{3}{2}a^3-9a \Rightarrow a^3-18a+28=0
$$

The only rational solution is $a=2$ i.e. $x+y=2$.

Comment: can you explain how you got a = x + y and b = xy, thanks.

Comment: You're cubic there factorizes as $(a-2)(a^2+2a-14)$ and the quadratic has positive dicriminant, so the cubic polynomial has three real roots.

Comment: @lolwut Sorry, meant rational, not real. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$ x + y = -1 + \sqrt{15} $ appears to be an additional solution.

The roots of the polynomial $a^3 - 18a + 28 = 0$ are 2, $-1 - \sqrt{15}$  ,  $\sqrt{15} - 1$